# How to add new thread for every new client in python websockets?

Tags: websocket, async-await, python-asyncio, python-sockets

```
import asyncio 
import websockets
import threading


async def server_handle(websocket,path):

    print("Server is waiting!!!!")

    while True:

        msg = await websocket.recv()

        print(f"Client : {msg}")

        await websocket.send(input("Server : "))


def add_new_clients():

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    start_server = websockets.serve(server_handle, "localhost", 1234)

    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)

    loop.run_forever()

    loop.close()


total_clients = 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # daemon server thread:
    server = threading.Thread(target=add_new_clients, daemon=True)
    server.start()

    total_clients+=1

    print(f"total clients : {total_clients}")
```

Here i am trying to add new thread to handle each clients request seperately using python websockets . for example if client1 connects to the server one thread should be created and sholud take care of the request and responce of that particular client. is there any way?.

Comment: Is there a reason why are you using multithreading and async programing simultaneously?

Comment: Actually i am trying to transcribe live audio which i am getting through websocket. I thought if i am able to create new thread for each client then the transcription will be very fast. if 2 people are speaking at the same time then there will be a delay in the transcription that's why.

Comment: multithreading in python does not give performance benefit other than IO operations, which your case falls into - but that's what Async is all about, so I'd say you'd better unify to either Asynchronous or Threading if possible. To know more about why Multithreading work that way in python, check out [GIL](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock)